# Permitting Remote Deskop Users group to login in

Tags: active-directory, domain, group-policy, remote-desktop, windows-terminal-services

I've been running into an issue where members of our IT department are unable to login to the servers we have recently set up. I have added the IT group to the Remote Desktop Users group and they are still unable to login.

In Group Policy if I give them the right to login locally and to login via Terminal Services then they are still unable to login. If I go to the local security policy and give them these rights there then they are able to login.

Unfortunately, this is not the best way to handle the problem seeing as we have multiple servers. I'd really hate to have to go through all 23 servers and update the local policy settings just so out IT Department can log in via RDC. Is there a way to fix this domain wide so that we can login to all the servers?

**Update:**

All users trying to login are domain users. The error they receive when logging in says:

```
To log on to this remote computer, you must be granted the Allow log on through Terminal Services right. By default, members of the Remote Desktop Users group have this right. If you are not a member of the Remote Deskop Users group or another group that has this right, or if the Remote Deskop User group does not have this right, you must be granted this right manually.
```

Comment: They using local account or domain account to login?

Comment: What do they get for an error?

Comment: I have updated my original question.

Comment: Do you using `gpupdate /force` after you edited domain controller policy?

Comment: No, I haven't done that. I'll try the group policy settings again and use gpupdate /force to see if it works.

Comment: Ok, even after using gpupdate /force the users are still unable to login remotely.